# Populate data from dropdown list using a load button

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to populate afew fields using a load button when I select from the dropdown list. However, the load button is not working and the php codes look fine to me. So I am wondering which part went wrong.

I am wondering if I should put the load button at AuthorityCode or below the form. However, I have tried both methods and both doesn't work.

```
<strong>Authority Code: </strong> 
<select name=authorityid value=authorityid>Select Authority</option>
<option value = "">Select</option><br/>
    <?php

$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");

$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT AuthorityId FROM AuthorityList");

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($authorityid);

while($stmt->fetch()){

    echo "<option value = '$authorityid'>$authorityid</option>";
}

$stmt->close();

$connection->close();

?>
</select>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"])){

$authorityid = $_POST["authorityid"];

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT AuthorityName, Address, TelephoneNo, FaxNo FROM AuthorityList WHERE AuthorityId = '$authorityid'");

$stmt->execute();

   $result = mysqli_query($stmt, $conn);
    $details = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $savedName = $details["AuthorityName"];
    $savedAddress = $details["Address"];
    $savedTel = $details["TelephoneNo"];
    $savedFax = $details["FaxNo"];
}
// while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
// $authorityname = $row[0];
// $address = $row[1];
// $telephone = $row[2];
// $fax = $row[3];
// }

?>

<form action="" method="post" >
<input type="submit" value="Load" name="loadbtn"><br/><br/>
<strong>Authority Name: </strong> <input type="text" name="authorityname" value="<?php echo $savedName; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Address: </strong> <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $savedAddress; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Telephone No: </strong> <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $savedTel; ?>"/><br/>

<strong>Fax No: </strong> <input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo $savedFax; ?>"/><br/>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: No error message, the load button doesn't populate the other fields

Comment: Try echoing the variables after you get them from mysql right after `$savedFax = $details["FaxNo"];`. Then again echo them using php after the `loadbtn` input type. What are you getting?

Comment: It just appear out on the website but dropdown list has no values

Comment: Does that mean your select options are not getting populated?

Comment: previously it was

Comment: Did you set the correct values in `mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");`?

Comment: @Rahul yes i did, and i used the method that you commented below

Comment: Are you getting result for `SELECT AuthorityId FROM AuthorityList`?

Comment: @Rahul yes able to get result as it appears in the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Your select values are not getting submitted as they are not part of the form. Also your 2nd query was not running properly. I've cheanged it below. Please take a look

Try this-

```
<strong>Authority Code: </strong> 
<form action="" method="post" >
    <select name="authorityid">Select Authority
        <option value = "">Select</option><br/>
        <?php
            $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
            $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT AuthorityId FROM AuthorityList");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($authorityid);
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<option value = '$authorityid'>$authorityid</option>";
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $connection->close();
        ?>
    </select>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"])){
            $authorityid = $_POST["authorityid"];
            $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
            $qry = "SELECT AuthorityName, Address, TelephoneNo, FaxNo FROM AuthorityList WHERE AuthorityId = '$authorityid'";

            $result = $conn->query($qry);
            $details = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $savedName = $details["AuthorityName"];
            $savedAddress = $details["Address"];
            $savedTel = $details["TelephoneNo"];
            $savedFax = $details["FaxNo"];
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Load" name="loadbtn"><br/><br/>
    <strong>Authority Name: </strong>
    <input type="text" name="authorityname" value="<?php echo isset($savedName) ? $savedName : ''; ?>"/>
    <br/>

    <strong>Address: </strong>
    <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo isset($savedAddress) ? $savedAddress : ''; ?>"/>
    <br/>

    <strong>Telephone No: </strong> 
    <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo isset($savedTel) ? $savedTel : ''; ?>"/>
    <br/>

    <strong>Fax No: </strong>
    <input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo isset($savedFax) ? $savedFax : ''; ?>"/>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Your error seems to be from mysql part of the code. Below you'll find a sample code that has mysql part removed from it and is running-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fix</title>
</head>
<body>
    <strong>Authority Code: </strong> 
    <form action="" method="post" >
        <select name="authorityid">Select Authority
            <option value = "">Select</option><br/>
            <?php
                echo "<option value = '123'>123</option>";
                echo "<option value = '234'>234</option>";
                echo "<option value = '345'>345</option>";
                echo "<option value = '456'>456</option>";
            ?>
        </select>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["loadbtn"])){
                $authorityid = $_POST["authorityid"];
                if ($authorityid == '123') {
                    $savedName = 'nameTest';
                    $savedAddress = 'addressTest';
                    $savedTel = 'telTest';
                    $savedFax = 'faxTest';
                }

            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Load" name="loadbtn"><br/><br/>
        <strong>Authority Name: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="authorityname" value="<?php echo isset($savedName) ? $savedName : ''; ?>"/>
        <br/>

        <strong>Address: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo isset($savedAddress) ? $savedAddress : ''; ?>"/>
        <br/>

        <strong>Telephone No: </strong> 
        <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo isset($savedTel) ? $savedTel : ''; ?>"/>
        <br/>

        <strong>Fax No: </strong>
        <input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo isset($savedFax) ? $savedFax : ''; ?>"/>
        <br/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited: changed the mysqli_query function so that it works properly.

Comment: Hi i have tried your method, fields still not populated

Comment: @DelwynTay Can you check if you're getting result from the queries?

Comment: Originally my method, I am able to get results from the dropdown list but upon clicking the load button, it does not populate the other fields i.e. address

Comment: Check if you're getting result for both your queries. Also check the developer tools to see if `authorityid` is getting submitted as POST after you select it and click Load

Answer (score 0):

Change form to:

```
<form action="window.location.reload()" method="post" >
```

Comment: <form action="window.location.reload()" method="post" >